# Composition of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

> $M$ denote the set of functions $y=\sin x, y=\arcsin x, y=\cos x, y=\arccos x, y=\tan x, y=\arctan x, y=\cot x, y=arccot x$.
>
> Is there a $n \in \mathbb N$ and such functions $f_1\in M, f_2\in M, ...,f_n\in M$ which
> $$f_1\left(f_2\left(...f_n\left(2016 \right) \right) \right)=1$$

#### My work so far:

If $f \in M$ that $f^{-1}\in M.$

Then we must find such functions $f_1\in M, f_2\in M, ...,f_n\in M$ which
$$f_1\left(f_2\left(...f_n\left(1 \right) \right) \right)=2016$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u(x) = \cos(\tan^{-1}(x)) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}\\
v(x) = \tan(\cot^{-1}(x)) = 1/x\\
v(u(x)) = \tan(\cot^{-1}(\cos(\tan^-1 (x))) = \sqrt{1+x^2}\\
v(u(1)) = \sqrt{2}\\
v(u(\sqrt{n})) = \sqrt{n+1}$

So, there is sequence of functions such that.

$f_1\circ f_2 \circ \cdots f_n(1) = 2016$

Since the inverse of each of these are in M then:

There is a sequence of functions in M such that:

$f_n^{-1}\circ f_{n-1}^{-1} \circ...f_1^{-1}(2016) = 1$